# Linux module Case label does not reduce to integer constant

Tags: c, linux-kernel, switch-statement, sizeof

I'm trying to use size of a struct A in

```
#define IOCTL_XYZ _IOWR(MAJOR_NUMBER, 10, A)
```

for defining an IOCTL but I get an error

```
error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
         case IOCTL_XYZ:
```

for IOCTL_XYZ not being an integer constant when using it with case statement in the ioctl handler.

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE1    4
#define ARRAY_SIZE2    4
#define ARRAY_SIZE3    8
#define ARRAY_SIZE4    4
#define ARRAY_SIZE5    6
    
typedef struct
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint64_t item1        :   4;
            uint64_t item2        :   4;
            uint64_t item3        :   8;
            uint64_t item4        :   48;
        };
        
        uint64_t combined;
    };
        
    union
    {
        uint64 array1[ARRAY_SIZE4];
        uint64 array2[ARRAY_SIZE5];
        uint64 array3[ARRAY_SIZE4];
    };
} B;
    
typedef struct
{
    uint64 element1;
    uint64 element2[ARRAY_SIZE1];        
    B element3[ARRAY_SIZE2];
    uint64 element4[ARRAY_SIZE3];
    
} A;
```

I have other ioctls which use structs like this for example:

```
typedef struct B
{
    uint32     item1;
    uint32     item2;
} B;
 
typedef struct C
{
    uint32 item1;
} C;

typedef struct
{
    uint32 item1;
    bool   item2;
    union
    {
        B  element1;
        C  element2;
    };
    uint32 item3;
} A;
```

and do not get this error.
Is it due to array of structs? But arrays have fixed size? How does the compiler not know the size at compile time in that case?

Comment: You have `ARRAY_SIZE6` in the code, but not in the definitions.  Is that a posting mistake or could it be the cause?  `sizeof(A)` will not be known as it is probably treating `ARRAY_SIZE6` as an integer variable, and the `IOWR()` expression is not a constant.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: @artlessnoise: Sorry, that was a posting mistake. I have updated the question.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it by filling in the gaps and replacing the invalid type names, but it worked for me. I guess you forgot to `#include` something?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error was one of the array sizes being too big for IOCTL which increased the total size over the allowed 16K limit.
I had edited the array sizes for this sample code in the question so it works fine.